# C++ template function are expected to throw exception?

Tags: c++, exception, noexcept

I was searching for reasons that prevent my compiler (intel 15) to vectorize my code. The reasons were : `loop with early exits cannot be vectorized unless it meets search loop idiom criteria` although I did not have any thing like `break` or `exit(0)` in it.
So I checked all my function with the `noexcept` operator and it seems that all my template function are likely to throw exception (the operator returns false all the time) althgough I have no try/catch/throw in it.
For this reason, I specify the `noexcept` on my function and now it works but I don't understand why the compiler say that they are likely to throw something ? How can I specify that, by default, they won't throw anything ??

Example:

```
/*.h*/
template <typename T>
void A(T& a){} /*does nothing*/

/*.cpp*/
#include ".h"
#include "MyClass.h"
int main(){
MyClass C;
noexcept(A(C)); /*Return false !!*/
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question - put `noexcept` on functions that don't/won't throw.

Comment: `noexcept()` will not examine your function definition. That would be intractable. If you want to be noexcept correct, you need to specify it. Just as you would with const correctness.

Comment: Also note, that if the function marked as `noexcept` will actually throw despite the specification, the exception cannot be caught (via try-catch) and the `std::terminate` will always be called (even if there is a try-catch block for the exception).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) (emphasis mine)

> The result is false if the expression contains at least one of the following potentially evaluated constructs:
>
> - call to any type of **function that does not have non-throwing exception specification**, unless it is a constant expression.
> - throw expression.
> - dynamic_cast expression when the target type is a reference type, and conversion needs a run time check
> - typeid expression when argument type is polymorphic class type
>
> In all other cases the result is true.

So as you noticed, the way to have your template function evaluate `noexcept` as `true` is simply to declare it as such

```
template <typename T>
void A(T& a) noexcept
{
}
```